# Preventing an Outlook mailitem from entering into a conflict

Tags: vba, networking, outlook, save, conflict

An outlook mailitem is on a network share, and is prone to conflicts especially when modifications are made to it.

The following VBA macro does the following:

1. Makes changes to a mailitem
2. Checks if the mailitem is saved and saves it.
3. Checks the saved mailitem for any conflicts.

How do I modify this code to prevent the mailitem from entering into a conflict in the first place?

Any ideas a welcome.

```
Sub CheckConflict()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objMail = olApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    objMail.Subject = "Changing subject and saving mail"
    If objMail.Saved = False Then
        objMail.Save
    End if

    If objMail.IsConflict = True Then
        Msgbox "Conflict detected!"
    End If
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimize the number of times you call Save and do not keep the MailItem object open for any prolonged periods of time.

Comment: Dmitry@ How about using a temporary dummy object? objMail_temp = objMail. Make modifications to objMail_temp, then set objMail = objMail_temp, and save objMail (once only) at the end. This way I don't have to worry about crashing objMail since it is not "opened" or "used" at all times. Is this implementable?

Comment: That won't make any difference - it won't even know (or care) that you are storing a reference to one of its objects in two variables.

Comment: Dmitry@ Alright. How about combining the two [if... end if] clauses into one? if objMail.IsConflict = False AND objMail.Saved = False then objmail.Save. Would this detect and prevent a conflict?

Comment: Why are you even saving the item? If it is being displayed by Outlook, would it not be the user's prerogative to decide when and if the item needs to be saved?

Comment: Dimitry@ Wait a minute. Are you saying that objMail.save is not necessary in a network-share? Does the exchange server automatically manage modifications made to the item?

Comment: No, I am saying that saving or not saving is up to the user. If the user decides not to save the message (just hits Esc), your code will force the message to be saved in the Drafts folder.

Comment: Dmitry@ Let me try to understand this correctly. I tried modifying the subject line using the macro code with the objMail.save part commented out. Unfortunately however, any modifications to the mailitem seems to get lost, the item never being forced into the drafts folder. The mailitem must be saved in order for the modifications to be updated. The user does not seem to have an option but to save the item, hence the exposure to conflicts.

Comment: Yes, but you are working with an item being displayed by Outlook at the time your code is running. If the user attempts to close the inspector, Outlook will prompt to save the changes Is that not what you are seeing?.